# Unsure how to troubleshoot Scrapy terminal output

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

and thanks in advance.

I'm attempting to use scrapy, which is somewhat new to me. I built (what I thought was) a simple spider which does the following:

```
class SuperSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'KYM_entries'
    start_urls = ['https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1']
 
    def parse(self, response):
        for entry in response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/section'):
            yield {
                # The link to a meme entry page on Know Your Meme
                'entry_link': entry.xpath('./td[2]/a/@href').get()
            }
```

Then I run the following in a terminal  window:

```
$ scrapy  crawl KYM_entries -O practice.csv
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.43ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 1.1build1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.7.1 started (bot: KYM_spider)
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.13, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022), cryptography 3.4.8, Platform Linux-5.15.0-56-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'KYM_spider',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'KYM_spider.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['KYM_spider.spiders']}
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [py.warnings] WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/request.py:231: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)

2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 97ac3d17f1e4cea1
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-12-26 20:08:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-12-26 20:08:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://knowyourmeme.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-12-26 20:08:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1> (referer: None)
2022-12-26 20:08:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-12-26 20:08:05 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 466,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11690,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.953839,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 27, 1, 8, 5, 833510),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 45804,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 65228800,
 'memusage/startup': 65228800,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 27, 1, 8, 4, 879671)}
2022-12-26 20:08:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

This returns an empty CSV, which I suppose means either something is wrong with the xpath, or there is something wrong with the connection to Know Your Meme. However, beyond the 200 code saying it is connecting to the site, I'm unsure how to troubleshoot what is happening here.

So I have a couple questions, one more direct to my issue, and one more broadly interested in this output:

1. Is there a way to see at what point my script is failing to retrieve the specified data in the xpath for this particular case?
2. Is there a simple guide or reference for how to read scrapy output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into your code. There are a few issues with the selectors/XPath.  I have updated the CSS selector and removed the XPATH. meme URLs are relative URLs so I have added urljoin method to make these URLs absolute URLs. I have added start_request method as my version of scrapy is 2.6.0. if you are using a lower version of scrapy (1.6.0) you can remove this method.

```
class SuperSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'KYM_entries'
    start_urls = ['https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse)
 
    def parse(self, response):
        for entry in response.css('.entry-grid-body .photo'):
            yield {
                # The link to a meme entry page on Know Your Meme
                'entry_link': response.urljoin(entry.css('::attr(href)').get())
            }
```

The code is working fine now. Below is the output.

```
2022-12-27 13:14:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-12-27 13:14:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-12-27 13:14:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1> (referer: None)
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/mayinquangcao'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-is-x-bitch-we-clown-in-this-muthafucka-betta-take-yo-sensitive-ass-back-to-y'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/choo-choo-charles'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/bug-fables-the-everlasting-sapling'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/onii-holding-a-picture'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/vintage-recipe-videos'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ytpmv-elf'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-just-hit-a-dog-going-70mph-on-my-truck'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/women-dodging-accountability'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/grinchs-ultimatum'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/where-is-idos-black-and-white'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/basilisk-time'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/rankinbass-productions'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/error143'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/whatsapp-university'}
2022-12-27 13:14:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all/page/1>
{'entry_link': 'https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/messi-autism-speculation-messi-is-autistic'}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This did definitely work. However I have a few questions, because I'm still new to this and trying to learn it.
1. Is it possible to translate this to XPath?
2. What does the "start_requests" function do here?

Comment: `start_requests` is calling the parse method, you can remove it if your scrapy version is 1.6.0.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm using scrapy 2.7.1 so I'm not sure if that means use it or not in this case, but it does work pretty well. I had to look up what is going on with the CSS selectors. I definitely see why the CSS seems more efficient in this case. I'm still struggling to understand the CSS selectors at this point. After looking into it, I think `'.entry-grid-body .photo'` translates to something like "find all photo nodes for all entry-grid-body objects" (is that correct?). And the second one, `'::attr(href)'` I'm definitely not sure of. But I'm guessing it means "the attribute href"?

Comment: What does the `::` mean? I've seen the use of one colon before, but I don't know what the double colon means.

Comment: you can read about selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php